# monotouch Iphone unique identifier or mac addres used by push notification

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, push-notification, uniqueidentifier, mac-address

I have found a method that brings the Unique identifier but its [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). Is there any other way to unique identify an iphone using monotouch software? If so, will it be accepted by Apple to authorize using push notifications?

I have thought about creating a GUID and save it on the phone. Not sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

Using the MAC address is likely the easiest option. You can list them using:

```
foreach (var i in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces ())
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}", i.Id, i.GetPhysicalAddress ());
```

However be warned that there was (it's fixed) a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2012) in MonoTouch when reading the MAC address. Make sure you're using a version that has that fix before releasing your application.

See this [email thread](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-November/006530.html) for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is adding your own GUID (unique identifier). 
First create a class somewhere.I choosed a folder called Domain. 
Here is the code

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;


public class Settings
{    

    private static string KEY_DEVICEID = "anyNameDeviceId";

    public static string DeviceId 
    {
        get
        {
            string result = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(KEY_DEVICEID);

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                result = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(result, KEY_DEVICEID); 
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize(); 
            }   

            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

then you just need to read in your view  this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Settings.DeviceId.toString());
```